# Parse Server Cloud Code set notifications badge to specific number

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am using cloud code on parse server to send push notifications to specific users on the app. Currently the badge is set to increment for each notification the user receives, which isn't bad, however I find it unattractive to see high numbers in the badge icon. I was wondering if instead of incrementing with each notification I can just set the badge number to be 1 so even if the user has 5 new notifications it will always say 1 in the corner.

Here is what my current javascript cloud code looks like

```js
  Parse.Cloud.define("mentions", function(request,response){
 
  var message = request.params.message;
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("user",request.params.User); 
 
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data : { 
      alert: message,
      badge: "increment",
    }
    }, {
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    response.success(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    response.error(error.message)
    },
  useMasterKey: true

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`badge: 1`, check the guide here:

http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#sending-options

Looks like that option is iOS only, though, so you won't be able to do this for Android.

The value should be a number, unless you are specifying "Increment" to add one to the current badge number.

Comment: after changing the quotes from "increment" to "1" it still does the same thing

Comment: Are you using `1` or `"1"`?

Comment: I used "1" with quotes

Comment: That would pass it as a string, and you want to pass it as a value. "Increment" should be the only string that can be used.

Comment: Can you edit the answer to reflect that badge should be an number and not a string? Otherwise that’s how it’s supposed to work

Comment: Updated, I didn't even notice I had the quotes around it. My apologies.

Comment: after changing from "badge": "1", to "badge": 1, there does not seem to be any difference. It is still incrementing the value each time

Comment: Could you update your question to reflect your current code?

Comment: @flovilmart Sorry for asking here, but couldn't find anywhere else appropriate to message you. Would you like me to add Parse.com as a tag synonym for Parse-Server, so we don't need to search for both tags to find relevant questions? Many people still use the Parse.com tag, and many questions about Parse.com are relevant now to Parse-Server, though it will also make a lot of historic, irrelevant questions related to the tag. If you think it's appropriate let me know and I can make that change.

Comment: @JakeT that would be AWESOME!

Comment: After trying it again it seems to be working, Thank you!!

Comment: @flovilmart Ahh, it doesn't allow me to add `parse.com` as a synonym for `parse-server`, since the former has more than 1.25x the number of uses as the latter. I could add `parse-server` as a synonym for `parse.com`, but that means any use of `parse-server` gets converted to `parse.com`. While basically functionally equivalent, it makes much more sense to go the other way, rather than reinforce the use of parse.com... Interesting conundrum. That being the case, let me know if you still want me to add the synonym. Otherwise, gotta wait until parse-server gets used a lot more than parse-server.

Comment: Can't we get a stackoverflow admin to take care of that??

Comment: @flovilmart I didn't see anywhere to request admin intervention on the page, nor do I know of any standard approach to messaging the admins. I just got the new ability to set tag synonyms with the 2500 rep or I wouldn't have known it existed.  As the maintainer of the SDKs, though, it'd probably be better for you to message them and ask about it than if I did.

Comment: I'll check it out then! Thanks for weeding it out!